# How to execute a Bash script when the OS starts (Kali Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, kali-linux

How do I set a script, written in bash, to execute when the operating system starts? I am on Kali Linux and have already added the permission of execution.

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that doesn't answer your question?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

firstly let your script file executable . chmod  a+x  file name .
 then run it by .\ file name .exe

Comment: this will not help it run at start up.